# Azure Upload Blob without Page Refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I'm following the Official Azure Blob Upload Documentation and I successfully implemented a blob uploading functionality. However the page refreshes after uploading and I need to make it in such as a way that the image is uploaded without the page having to refresh. Basically no postback.

Here's what I have so far:

```
       if (profile_pic_input.HasFile)
       {
                var image = Request.Files["profile_pic_input"];

                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);
                CloudBlobClient blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference("photos");
                if (container.CreateIfNotExists())
                {
                    // configure container for public access
                    var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
                    permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
                    container.SetPermissions(permissions);
                }


                String tempName = GeneratePictureName();
                string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("photos/image_{0}{1}", tempName, Path.GetExtension(image.FileName));
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);



                blob.Properties.ContentType = image.ContentType;
                blob.UploadFromStream(image.InputStream);
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid postback, you would need to use [`AJAX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Most of the common JavaScript frameworks like [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) support that.

Now coming on to uploading files into blob storage using AJAX, there are essentially two ways you can do it:

1. **Upload directly into Blob Storage from user's browser**: If your users are using modern browsers which support HTML5, then they can directly upload files from their local computers into blob storage. Please see this link for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh824678.aspx. Essentially what you would do is create a `Shared Access Signature` with at least `Write` permission and allow cross-origin requests (CORS) from your web application to your storage account. This way the files are transferred directly received into your storage account. I have also written a blog post about the same that you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/.
2. **Upload files from your user's browser to your web server and then transfer the file into blob storage**. If you search for AJAX and File Upload, I'm sure you will find a lot of resources which will tell you how that would work.

My recommendation would be to go with option #1 as it is much faster and does not overload your web servers.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. I actually landed on your website and read that article a few minutes ago before you posted. Vey informative. However, it seems a bit complex.. that's alright, I'll give it a try. Where in that code does it look for the file uploader's file that needs to be uploaded?

Comment: Please see `reader.onloadend` function in my blog post. That's where the upload magic happens :). `Web Application` section is what you want to read and understand.

Comment: Since it's a console app, in my case which method do I have to add to the upload button click mate? Could please you explain it using an answer mate? Major help, Gaurav

Comment: Now I'm confused :). I thought you wanted it in a web application. Where did this console application come from?

Comment: Ooops my bad sorry. Basically mine is a aspx page which has a input file control and a button (just for testing purposes). When the button is clicked the image is uploaded to the storage but the page refreshes. So by referring to your code, what changes can I make to the existing code which I posted in my question, Gaurav? I'm a bit confused as to how to add your code to my existing one :)

Comment: No worries :). Its been quite some time that I've worked with aspx files (using MVC lately). Let try it out on my end and revert back. Basic thing is that your submit button will not fire a postback event. Rather it will call a JavaScript function and that will upload the file directly into storage.

Comment: btw in your example, how do I generate the SAS for my container?

Comment: Please take a look at this blog post: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82364/discussion-between-earthling-and-gaurav-mantri).